# I have tried converting spring integration xml config to java config. I am facing some problems which I have discussed below

Tags: spring-integration

Tried two approaches given below but not working. I have given the problems i am facing with the approaches below.
Xml config : error with 1st config:

> Error : Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.integration.mail.Pop3MailReceiver]: Factory method 'pop3MailReceiver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Service

```
<int:channel id="receiveEmailChannel" />
    <util:properties id="javaMailProperties">
        <prop key="mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback">false</prop>
        <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
        <prop key="mail.pop3.port">995</prop>
        <prop key="mail.pop3.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
        <prop key="mail.pop3.socketFactory.port">995</prop>
    </util:properties>

    <int-mail:inbound-channel-adapter id="pop3ShouldDeleteTrue"
        store-uri="pop3://[user name]:[pwd]pop.gmail.com/INBOX"
        channel="receiveEmailChannel" should-delete-messages="false"
        auto-startup="true" java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties">

        <int:poller fixed-rate="5000" max-messages-per-poll="5"></int:poller>
    </int-mail:inbound-channel-adapter>




    <int:channel id="attachment-insert-channel" />
    <int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter
        channel="attachment-insert-channel" data-source="dataSource" query="${attachment-insert-query}">
    </int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter>


    <int:channel id="printSqlResult" />
    <int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter
        channel="printSqlResult" data-source="dataSource" query="${insert-query}">
    </int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ap_mail" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

1st java config :

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class MailConfig {

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel inputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    private Properties javaMailProperties() {
        Properties javaMailProperties = new Properties();

        javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback","false");
        javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.store.protocol","imaps");
        javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.debug","true");

        return javaMailProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public Pop3MailReceiver pop3MailReceiver() {
        Pop3MailReceiver receiver = new Pop3MailReceiver("pop3://[un]:[pwd]@pop.gmail.com/INBOX");
        receiver.setJavaMailProperties(javaMailProperties());
        receiver.setShouldDeleteMessages(false);
        //receiver.setChannelResolver((DestinationResolver<MessageChannel>) inputChannel());
        return receiver;
    }

}
```

2nd java config : removed 1st@Bean public Pop3MailReceiver pop3MailReceiver() and used this

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow pop3MailFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Mail.pop3InboundAdapter("localhost", "995", "user", "pw")
                .javaMailProperties(p -> p.put("mail.debug", "true")),e -> e.autoStartup(true)
                .poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(60000)))
                .channel(MessageChannels.queue("pop3Channel"))
                .get();
    }
```

the problem with this is  unable to import IntegrationFlows,Mail even though they are in my maven dependencies

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.muraai.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-java-dsl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>

                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see from your question in the stack trace it is saying no class def error

**threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Service**

which generally means that that  mail.jar is missing from the classpath or from the place where application is loading, check your classpath to see if  all the jar files are present or not.

Comment: this works fine but how to specify channel in this approach. Can you check my 2nd config

Comment: can you please share the stack trace of what error you are getting in the second config